# Dapper Npgsql DbString character vayring parameters

Tags: dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to use Dapper to call a PostreSQL function declared as the following:

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(param1 integer, param2 character varying, param3 character varying)

I'm using **Dapper-Async** to call this function like this:

> cnx.QueryAsync($@"SELECT * FROM public.test(@Param1, @Param2, @Param3);",
>   new { Param1 = 12, Param2 = mylongstring1, Param3 = mylongstring2});

This call fails with the following error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: function public.test(integer, text, text) does not exist

As you can see, the **DbString** matches **text** parameter types.
How can I match **character varying** instead ?

Comment: @roji This is another issue. I used the same samples.

Comment: Apologies - I was too quick, deleted.

Comment: Do you want me to open an issue on github ?

Comment: For now this looks like a simple parameter type mismatch (see my answer below), if it turns out to be an Npgsql problem then an issue would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably the fact that your function is defined with parameter type `character varying`, but as the error shows you're sending `text`. While this may be somewhat confusing, these are two different backend types.

By default, Npgsql maps .NET string to `text`, not to `character varying`. You can either change your function to accept `text` (or add an overload), or use `NpgsqlDbType` to specify `character varying` (not sure how to do this with Dapper though).

Comment: Well there was a typo in the function name :-( It works with character wayring so PostgreSQL seems to do all the work.

Comment: @ShayRojansky The issue still remains. At the moment the only solution I have found is to change the signature for the function... string is mapped to text type for npgsql.

Comment: Another solution is to use `Dapper.Query<T>` instead of `Dapper.Execute<T>`.. that way, one can cast the parameter type to `character varying`...